# Why double the size when growing an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Could you please explain me what is the point of doubling the size of an array when we want to create an array of the arbitrary size (offered in one ebook):

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *growArray (int* p_values, int cur_size);
int main ()
{
int next_element = 0;
int size = 10;
int *p_values = new int[ size ];
int val;
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
cin >> val;
while ( val > 0 )
{
if ( size == next_element + 1 )
{
// now all we need to do is implement growArray
p_values = growArray( p_values, size );
}
p_values[ next_element ] = val;
cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
cin >> val;
}
}
int *growArray (int* p_values, int cur_size)
{
int *p_new_values = new int[ cur_size * 2 ];
for ( int i = 0; i < cur_size; ++i )
{
p_new_values[ i ] = p_values[ i ];
}
delete p_values;
return p_new_values;
}
```

Can't we just do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main ()
{
int next_element = 0;
int size = 10;
int *p_values = new int[ size ];
int val;
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
cin >> val;
while ( val > 0 )
{

p_values[ next_element ] = val;
cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
cin >> val;
next_element += 1;
if (next_element > size) size += 1;

}

for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {

    cout << p_values[i]; }

cin.get();
cin.ignore();

}
```

Comment: If you grow the array one element at a time, you end up with quadratic behaviour as you copy the elements from array to array+1 to array+2.  Doubling reduces the cost to linear time.

Comment: This growth strategy gives you get so-called "amortized constant time insertions". If you search for that term, you will find more info easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically emulating a `std::vector` with a rather naive allocation approach; if you just increase by 1, you're very likely to do that size increase very often (which is a very computational intensive operation!

That's the reason why vectors usually grow more than just one element; allocating memory and copying over all existing data is just so expensive that you want to minimize the probability of that, of course without allocating *all* the memory at the very beginning. Doubling the allocated size thus really makes sense as a tradeoff.

By the way, in your code, increasing the `size` variable doesn't give you any more memory... accessing `array[size]` thus would simply give you whatever is in memory right after your last element (or a segmentation fault, if that memory doesn't belong to your processes' virtual memory space).

Comment: :) thanks for accepting. Usually, you'd also upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using your second method, p_values is initialized only once at the beginning, as an integer array of size 10.

```
int *p_values = new int[ size ];
```

Changing the value of the size variable afterwards does not change this, p_values will remain of size 10 until you change where it points to. So after 10 entries, you will have a crash.

That's what the growArray function in your book's example is for: expanding the maximum capacity of your array:

```
int *p_new_values = new int[ cur_size * 2 ];
for ( int i = 0; i < cur_size; ++i )
{
    p_new_values[ i ] = p_values[ i ];
}
delete p_values;
```

It first defines a totally new array of a bigger size (twice).
Then, it copies the already existing values from the new array to the new array.
Then it deletes the old array to save some memory and all you have to do is to use the new "p_new_values" variable.

EDIT: as said in other answers, the best approach would be to directly use a vector, which is a structure made purposely to simplify this problem. But I guess your book will explain this later on.
And as of why doubling the size, it could be +10, or whatever, but everytime you call the growArray function, you have to copy all the data again, which is not that good, so you want to avoid doing it too often. Doubling is usually a good choice.